# failed to load ldlinux.c32

Tags: boot, usb

I am a newbie and hardly know anything about ubuntu.
I want to try it.

I followed this youtube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_Ja2PRt0cc

It worked perfectly and the usb key is ready.

Now i had to change the boot priority
I made USB KEY the top most priority and restarted the computer with the usb.

But I get this error message

> Failed to load ldlinux.c32  Boot Failed : Please change disks and
>   press a key to continue

Can you please teach me how to fix it. A video would be too useful.

Laptop : Samsung R428
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: is secure boot off?

Comment: I bumped into the same problem while trying to run BIOS update utility for Thinkpad T470s. I finally [followed this tutorial using `dd`](https://workaround.org/article/updating-the-bios-on-lenovo-laptops-from-linux-using-a-usb-flash-stick/).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is because your flash drive has FAT32 format and your BIOS can't see it (because it is old). After I have formatted my flash drive with FAT16 everything went fine.

I have used 2gb flash drive and Rufus software to make bootable drive. I have tried to use larger flash drive (8gb) but my BIOS still had the same error.
So if you use Rufus choose FAT option (which means FAT16) while making bootable drive.

BTW: If you have only 1gb flash drive you can write the Lubuntu (it is light weight).